# current time minus the submitted time

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

im making a mini attendance module, but i dont have a idea to do this so please help me and the user must attend every 3hrs so if they attend at 3:05 the difference from time will be the value of `$late`

this is my code of getting the time to show in the page

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
if (minutes < 10){
minutes = "0" + minutes
}
document.write(hours + ":" + minutes + " ")
if(hours > 11){
document.write("PM")
} else {
document.write("AM")
}
```

so im planning to get the time into the database by using this

```
INSERT INTO time_in(late,time_in)
        VALUES ('$late,NOW())";
```

and my big problem.
is how can i get the difference from time required? and how can i insert the difference into my database?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Date object defines a method called `.getTime()` which converts the object to an integer, number of milliseconds from 01.01.1970 00:00:00.

So the difference could be calculated like this :

```
var before = new Date('2017-02-07 06:00:00');
var after = new Date('2017-02-07 07:00:00');
var diff = after.getTime() - before.getTime();
// 3600000 milliseconds
```

or using (+) shortcut for the same:

```
var diff = +before- +after;
```

You say the users must attend to something in every 3 hours so the difference from the latest attendance time would be calculated like this :

```
var now = new Date();
var attTime = new Date(+now - (+now % (3*3600*1000)));
var minutesLate = Math.round((+now - +attTime)/60000);
```

Comment: hi, sorry for asking this but how do i write that in my codes?

Comment: Rename 'now' to 'currentTime' and 'minutesLate' to 'late' on the last code block and paste it in your code where just before the db call.

Comment: Create a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) with your code then I'll take a look what's wrong.